# Creating a sparse matrix with SciPy in Python

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I am trying to create a sparse matrix by reading the documentation.

So, according to the documentation (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html):

[image]

When I try:

```
csr_matrix((data = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]), indices = np.array(2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 7), indptr = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1])))
```

I get an exception:

> File "", line 1
>       csr_matrix((data = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]), indices = np.array(2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 7), indptr = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1])))
>                        ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

When I try:

```
csr_matrix((np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]), np.array(2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 7), np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1])))
```

again an error message results:

> ValueError: only 2 non-keyword arguments accepted

My intention here is to create a matrix which has ones in the columns with indexes
2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 7
where the corresponding rows have indexes
0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1

(i.e., (0, 2) , (1, 3) , (2, 4) etc).

Comment: The first uses assignment not allowed. The second has missing brackets inside numpy's constructor (`np.array(1,2,3)`  is not going to work). Grab the docs of all the functions involved, **including** `np.array()`.

Comment: Pay close attention to the use of ().

Comment: Yes you are right, it was a typo after all.

Answer (score 0):

You should be all set with

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
import numpy as np

my_csr = csr_matrix((np.array([1,1,1,1,1,1]), (np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1]), np.array([2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 7]))), shape = (8,8))
```

Note that you need to specify the shape of the matrix (here I set the matrix to be a square 8x8 matrix via the parameter `shape`). Note also the order of the arrays and the use of round brackets!

You can verify that this is satisfactory by converting to a dense format:

```
my_csr.toarray()
```